# Proof by induction. Two matrices are equal.

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, induction

I think i have this proof figured out but I just want a second opinion.

We have matrices $A=B$. $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&1\\0&a\end{pmatrix}^n$$   $$B=\begin{pmatrix}a^n&n a^{n-1}\\0&a^n\end{pmatrix}$$

My base case I used $n=1$ and I was able to get them to equal.
Next with my induction step I set $n=k$ and assumed that the base cases holds. So then I let $n=k+1$ and I got matrix $A$ to look nice. However when i did this process with matrix $B$ it did not equal matrix $A$.

So with this i continued to solve through and i have gotten them almost identical but i feel like i am missing a step.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE . Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question . Wish you luck and glad to have you here.:)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

If it is true for $n=k$ then:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&1\\0&a\end{pmatrix}^k=\begin{pmatrix}a^k&k a^{k-1}\\0&a^k\end{pmatrix}$$

so:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&1\\0&a\end{pmatrix}^{k+1}=\begin{pmatrix}a&1\\0&a\end{pmatrix}^{k} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}a&1\\0&a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a^k&k a^{k-1}\\0&a^k\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}a&1\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$$
and by computing the last product you obtain:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a^{k+1}&(k+1) a^{k+1-1}\\0&a^{k+1}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you, i think that i found my mistake and what you said really helped